# SIGSEGV in _dl_fini

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, segmentation-fault

I was hoping for some insights into debugging a problem I have been wrestling with for two days now. This is the situation

- I am working on two shared object files, let's call them `libMyA.so` and `libMyB.so`, that are part of a product.
- These two shared object files each link two static library, `libMyC.a` and `libMyD.a`
- `libMyA.so` and `libMyB.so` I have unit tests which are basically command line executables that invoke some of the functions exported by the shared objects, `blackboxA` and `blackboxB`.
- `libMyB.so` makes used of functions exported by `libMyA.so`. A few functions of `libMyA.so` are invoked in the init function of `libMyB.so` (just the generation of a few STL containers).

What happens is this:

- `blackboxA` runs smooth and passes all tests.
- `blackboxB` also passes all tests, but upon termination it raises a `SIGSEGV`.

gdb tells me that the `SIGSEGV`happens during execution of the finalizer of `libMyB.so` inside the destructor of a `std::basic_string<char>` object:

```
#0  0x00007ffff74a0bc3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff74a0c13 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff6b6cd1d in __cxa_finalize (d=0x7ffff7dd4d80) at cxa_finalize.c:56
#3  0x00007ffff7b1d7b6 in __do_global_dtors_aux () from ./libMinosCVC.so.3
#4  0x00007fffffffe3a0 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007fffffffe480 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007ffff7b9a541 in _fini () from ./libMinosCVC.so.3
#7  0x00007fffffffe480 in ?? ()
#8  0x00007ffff7de992d in _dl_fini () at dl-fini.c:259
```

I am aware, that std::string objects defined at global or namespace scope in a static library may be problematic when that static library is linked by more than one shared object in the process, and have skimmed `libMyC.a` and `libMyD.a` for string objects at those scoped without success so far.

I have also modified `blackboxB` to the extent where the main function only consisted of a `return 0` - the `SIGSEGV` persisted. If I modify `libMyB.so` to longer call anything from `libMyA.so` in its init function the `SIGSEGV`vanishes.

Is there any means I am not aware of for detecting the actual object that the libc is trying to clean up when the SIGSEGV happens? gdb did point out the `std::string` destructor, but nothing beyond that (even access to `std::string` members was not possible). valgrind was not much help, either...

Oh, I almost forgot the cherry on top: When built with -O0 everything works, only the -O2 build crashes.

Thanks for any input on this nightmare...

Comment: Finally got rid of the SIGSEGV for now after I removed every declaration & definition of a `std::string` that I could find in the source of `libMyB.so`. Still  haven't understood, why those could actually be an issue in this scenario - I'd have understood to some extent in the static libs, but the shared ones...?  Bottom line is I'll need to learn more about the behavior of `ld`.  I won't 'answer' this question (I am aware that it might remain unanswered) as the removal of the symptom does not really qualify as an answer in this case...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***NOTE: This answer was provided to me by a coworker that wishes to remain anonymous but wants to be helpful. I take no credit in solving this issue.***

I encountered a problem at work with similar symptoms.
this answer outlines how i approached that problem.
most/all of this info is available elsewhere on the internet, but i couldn't find it consolidated like this, and, as someone not 'in the know', it wasn't terribly obvious to me in the beginning (and is only a little more obvious to me now).
apologies in advance if i get anything wrong...

---

some info on the machine i'm using:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago)
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)
...
$ /lib64/libc.so.6
GNU C Library stable release version 2.12, by Roland McGrath et al.
...
$ uname -srm
Linux 2.6.32-696.6.3.el6.x86_64 x86_64
```

---

a minimal-ish working example:

`common.h`:

```cpp
#include <string>
struct Common {
  static const std::string s;
};
```

`common.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "common.h"
const std::string Common::s("common");
```

`main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "common.h"
int main(void) {
  std::cout << Common::s << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

build (debugging symbols help, but probably aren't strictly necessary):

```
$ g++ -g -shared -fPIC common.cpp -o libone.so
$ g++ -g -shared -fPIC common.cpp -o libtwo.so
$ g++ -g main.cpp -L. -lone -ltwo -o main
```

run (note that it might just run fine...):

```
$ # turn on core dumping
$ ./main
common
*** glibc detected *** ./main: double free or corruption (...): 0x... ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x...]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x...]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSsD1Ev+0x...)[0x...]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__cxa_finalize+0x...)[0x...]
libtwo.so(+0x...)[0x...]
======= Memory map: ========
...
Aborted (core dumped)
$
```

check the core:

```
$ gdb -c core.<pid> -e main
...
Core was generated by `./main'.
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
#0  0x... in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x... in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x... in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x... in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x... in malloc_printerr () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x... in _int_free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x... in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x... in __cxa_finalize () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#7  0x... in __do_global_dtors_aux () from /libtwo.so
#8  0x... in ?? ()
```

---

some exposition, to the best of my knowledge:

at startup, before `main`, static destructors get registered with `__cxa_atexit` (or similar) as the statics are initialized.
then, before a 'regular' exit, the program goes through and calls the registered destructors in reverse order.
`__cxa_atexit` takes 3 arguments.
1st is a function (eg. class dtor).
2nd is arg for function in 1st arg (eg. `std::string*`).
3rd arg i'll ignore...
on x86-64 on linux (platform i'm working on), 1st,2nd args get passed in `%rdi`,`%rsi` respectively.
the idea is to break on `__cxa_atexit`, log what's in the registers, and look for duplicates when the program's done with its startup.

some context to go with the register contents would be useful.
gdb backtrace looks something like this:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x... in __cxa_atexit_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x... in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (...) at common.cpp:2
#2  0x... in global constructors keyed to _ZN6Common1sE () at common.cpp:3
#3  0x... in __do_global_ctors_aux () from libone.so
#4  0x... in _init () from libone.so
...
```

frames 3/4 get you which binary file to look at (eg. for disassembly).
frame 2 gets you roughly which block of source code the static is associated with.
frame 1 gets you where in the appropriate binary file to look.
a few instructions before the instruction listed for frame 1, you should see which address gets loaded to `%rsi`.

---

```
$ gdb --args ./main
...
(gdb) b __cxa_atexit
Breakpoint 1 at 0x...
(gdb) comm
...
>silent
>printf "$rdi %p $rsi %p\n", $rdi, $rsi
>bt 4
>c
>end
(gdb) set pag off
(gdb) set log redirect on
(gdb) set log file __cxa_atexit.txt
(gdb) set log on
Redirecting output to __cxa_atexit.txt.
(gdb) start
(gdb) set log off
Done logging to __cxa_atexit.txt.
(gdb)
```

note that the pag/log settings above are optional.
not a big difference in this example, but in the 'actual' program i was working with, the `__cxa_atexit` breakpoint was reached several thousand times (and took several minutes to reach the temporary breakpoint at `main`).

look for duplicate register lines in the output:

```
grep "^\$rdi" __cxa_atexit.txt | sort | uniq -d
```

i check the address in `%rdi` as a feel-good sanity check:

```
(gdb) x/i 0x...
   0x... <_ZNSsD2Ev>: ...

$ c++filt _ZNSsD2Ev
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()
```

or, use gdb's `i shared` or `i proc map` listings to get an offset and use a disassembler on the appropriate binary (don't forget to [offset your offset if needed](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6657/why-does-ldd-and-gdb-info-sharedlibrary-show-a-different-library-base-addr)).

the associated backtraces look something like this:

```
#0  0x... in __cxa_atexit_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x... in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (...) at common.cpp:2
#2  0x... in global constructors keyed to common.cpp(void) () at common.cpp:2
#3  0x... in __do_global_ctors_aux () from libone.so
```

if you look in the binary listed in frame 3, a few instructions before the instruction listed in frame 1, you should see what gets loaded to `%rsi` before the call to `__cxa_atexit`.
with this example, objdump annotates it with an 'absolute offset' and `_ZN6Common1sE@@Base-0x80` for me.
the 'absolute offset' should match what's listed under the "Offset" column of the output of `readelf -rW` for the respective symbol.

the source line listing for frame 1 tells you which static is getting 'duplicated', and you can follow the backtrace up to see how it's getting included in two different binaries, compare that with how your binaries are being built, etc.
if you built without debugging symbols, you won't get the source line listings, and you might have to do some disassembly to figure out where in the source code to look.

---

near the beginning, i listed some machine info.
here's another machine i have access to:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)
...
$ /lib64/libc.so.6
GNU C Library stable release version 2.5, by Roland McGrath et al.
...
$ uname -srm
Linux 2.6.18-164.el5 x86_64
```

the above outline won't work when built on this machine because instead of registering the dtor's with `__cxa_atexit`, the dtor's are instead wrapped by functions like `__tcf_0`,`__tcf_1`,etc. which are registered with `__cxa_atexit`.
so you may have multiple (possibly slightly different?) `__tcf_*` functions which destruct the same static.
if you wanted to catch this at program startup, you might have to do some programmatic (dis)assembly inspection (which i don't know how to do).
you could try to catch this at program shutdown, breaking on calls to `~string`,`free`,`_int_free`,etc., comparing 1st arg to previous 1st arg's, then saving 1st arg somewhere for future comparison (gdb/python?).
or, you could do some generous 'regular' logging and look for double free's post-mortem.

the change seems to have gone in in gcc-4.3.0.
see `gcc-g++-4.3.0.tar.{gz,bz2}`, file `gcc/cp/decl.c`, functions `start_cleanup_fn`,`register_dtor_fn`.
ChangeLog snippet:

> 2007-05-31  Mark Mitchell  <email>
>
> * decl.c (get_atexit_fn_ptr_type): New function.
>           (get_atexit_node): Use it.
>           (start_cleanup_fn): Likewise.
>           (register_dtor_fn): Use the object's destructor, instead of a
>           separate cleanup function, where possible.
>           ...

Comment: very good exposition! But with `g++` version 7.5 I cannot make it to link two identical shared libraries. I have a similar situation with overlinking the same library to an executable and the dependencies of the executable. Just wanted to confirm that it is the same problem.

Comment: Seems has something to do with double linking to the same library.  I encounter the same problem.  Good posting.